# E: Unable to locate package xmkmf

Tags: 14.04, tightvncserver

I wanted to re-install tightvnc server from 1.3.9 to 1.3.10 because whenever I log in to the box, vnc crashes after 30+ mins. In my 
 google expedition I came across these set of commands

```
pushd ~
sudo apt-get install xorg-dev libjpeg62-dev zlib1g-dev xmkmf
mkdir -p vnc-problem/new
cd vnc-problem/new
wget http://www.tightvnc.com/download/1.3.10/tightvnc-1.3.10_unixsrc.tar.gz
tar xzf tightvnc-1.3.10_unixsrc.tar.gz
cd vnc_unixsrc
xmkmf
make World
cd Xvnc
./configure
time make
sudo mv /usr/bin/Xtightvnc /usr/bin/Xtightvnc-1.3.9
sudo cp programs/Xserver/Xvnc /usr/bin/Xtightvnc-1.3.10
sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/Xtightvnc-1.3.10
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/Xtightvnc-1.3.10
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/Xtightvnc Xtightvnc /usr/bin/Xtightvnc-1.3.9 50
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/Xtightvnc Xtightvnc /usr/bin/Xtightvnc-1.3.10 60
sudo update-alternatives --config Xtightvnc # choose Xtightvnc-1.3.10
sudo update-alternatives --set Xtightvnc /usr/bin/Xtightvnc-1.3.10
popd
```

from this [solution](http://pietercvdmlinux.blogspot.co.ke/2010/07/running-tightvncserver-on-ubuntu-1004.html) and decided to give it a try. When I ran this command `sudo apt-get install xorg-dev libjpeg62-dev zlib1g-dev xmkmf` I got this response on my commandline.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package xmkmf
```

I have also installed `xutils-dev` package as per this [response](https://serverfault.com/questions/336954/how-to-get-install-xmkmf)
.Anyone with a clue?

Comment: What is `xmkmf`? What makes you think it exists and is needed? [As far as I can tell](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=xmkmf&mode=exactfilename&suite=artful&arch=any), it is provided by `xutils-dev` so why are you still trying to install it?

Comment: @terdon in other words are you trying to say I exclude it in my command?

Comment: Yes. The instructions you ate following are from 2010

Comment: @karel the OP has already installed tightvnc, the question is about problems running it, not installing it.

Comment: @terdon It said in the blog linked to in the question "I had to install the following dependencies to build the source: xorg-dev libjpeg62-dev zlib1g-dev xmkmf" and the OP can't install xmkmf so I assumed from that line that he hasn't managed to install tightvncserver 1.3.10 yet either, but if I'm wrong I'll start deleting stuff.

Comment: @karel please read the first sentence of the question: "*I wanted to **re-install** tightvnc server from 1.3.9 to 1.3.10 because whenever I log in to the box, **vnc crashes** after 30+ mins.*"

Comment: I still think the OP has 1.3.9 currently installed. Do you think the OP has 1.3.10 currently installed, not 1.3.9?

Comment: I currently have v1.3.9 installed and it works, however it crashes after some time. One of the solution I found is to install 1.3.10 because of its stability.In the process of installation, I got the above error

Comment: @bademba wait, that's different. You are showing us the output of `apt-get install xorg-dev libjpeg62-dev zlib1g-dev xmkmf`. This doesn't install tightvnc. Have you actually managed to install tightvnc or not?

Comment: @terdon that is the output of a command I ran as  part of the solution I got from the link I shared above

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what the *current* situation is. Karel has understood that you can't install tightvncserver 1.3.10 while I understand that you can but it doesn't work well. So please [edit] and clarify what is actually going on. The `xmkmf` is irrelevant since, as was pointed out before, that is included in `xutils-dev`. Is that the only problem you have?

Comment: @terdon that was my challenge. That is why I asked if I should exclude it from my command.I have also edited my problem statement to make it more clearer.

Comment: So is your basic question "Why can't I install xmkmf" or is the question "How can I install tightvncserver 1.3.10"? Does installing tightvnc as described in Karel's answer solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

tightvncserver 1.3.10 for Ubuntu 16.04 can be manually downloaded and installed in your Ubuntu 14.04. No additional dependencies are required to install it in Ubuntu 14.04.

Visit the official [Ubuntu - Details of package tightvncserver in xenial](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/tightvncserver) website and download the tightvncserver package that matches your OS's architecture.

1. Click the OS architecture printed in red in the **Download tightvncserver** table ([amd64](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/tightvncserver/download) or [i386](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/i386/tightvncserver/download)).
2. Select a mirror from the list of mirrors and download the tightvncserver .deb file (either tightvncserver_1.3.10-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb or tightvncserver_1.3.10-0ubuntu3_i386.deb depending on your OS's architecture) to your Desktop.
3. Double-click the tightvncserver .deb file that you downloaded to open it for installation in the Ubuntu Software Center.
4. Run the following command to prevent tightvncserver from being automatically installed, upgraded or removed.

   ```
   sudo apt-mark hold tightvncserver
   ```

Comment: -1 "One-time" installations of packages are a security risk since updates will not be automatically installed.

Comment: The alternative is to find a PPA that has the same package which is possibly a much greater security risk than my way of installing tightvncserver 1.3.10, because it adds all the software in that PPA (**P**ersonal **P**ackage **A**rchive) to the software sources. Software from a PPA is at least updated by the Software Updater app, so it's not a security risk that way.

Comment: @fkraiem um, what? First of all, this isn't a one time thing, only the 14.04 approach is suggesting not to use the normal repositories. Second, that's not a security risk! You sometimes *need* to install things that aren't in the repos. Sure, you will then need to keep it updated, but that doesn't make this approach a security risk by definition.

Comment: @terdon The answer does not say how you keep it updated; not even that you need to do it at all.